# Why struct is giving wrong sizeof and void pointer

Tags: c

1. Why is `sizeof` giving the wrong output?
2. What is meant by `void pointer`? Why is it 4 bytes?

In this code:

```
struct s1
{
    int p;
    void *q;
    char r;
};
struct s2
{
    int p;
    char r;
    void *q;
};
int main()
{
    struct s1 s;
    struct s2 r;
    printf("%d %d",sizeof(s),sizeof(r));
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(int),sizeof(char),sizeof(void*));
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting output as 12 but I think `sizeof` should give 9 as answer.

What is this padding I have heard about in many posts?

Comment: Yes, padding, you've heard of it, did you try google for it? There are many useful result if you google , e.g, *c struct padding*

Comment: possible duplicate of [structure padding and structure packing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)

Comment: the return type of `sizeof` is `size_t` which is an unsigned type and you need `%zu` to print it. Printing with the wrong format is undefined behavior

Comment: Next time, rather than ask why the compiler is wrong, consider alternates sources.

Comment: Suggest work on reformatting code (see my edits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not giving wrong output. The size of int on your system would be 4, the size of a void pointer also 4, and while char can usually be 8 bits long, the struct itself will not be 9 bytes long, as most systems are at least 32 bit, so the compiler is "padding" them to be multiples of 4 bytes.
A void pointer is just a pointer that can point to anything.